# Transform from ortho view to normal view

Tags: transforms

I designed a character, for that, I used a blueprint.

The object looks very good in ortho view (when you press <kbd>5</kbd>), but when you go back to the normal view, it looks strange.

How can I transform the object so that it looks in perspective view the same as in ortho view.

When I say ortho, I mean when you press <kbd>5</kbd>

Comment: Firstly, it seems like you accidentally posted before finishing. There is an edit button you can use to type the rest of your question.

Second, you will need to be a little more specific. Sayin "it looks strange" isn't really enough information for us to help, so if you could say what specifically was wrong with it then you will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: It lookes warped. It looke in the ortho view like a normal humain and in the normal view like an human fass that is warped. Like the dimension are not correct

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: As suggested, please add images to your question so that other people can see how your model is distorted - otherwise it's very difficult for anyone to suggest ways of correcting it without guesswork as to what the problem could be. It sounds like this could be a case for the proportional edit tool - with the falloff set to linear - which could be used to fix a perspective issue with your model but there's too little information to write a proper answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press "N" to enter the properties menu, go down to where it says View and increase the lens size, I remember hearing that can assist if your model looks distorted in the default camera.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer